# Do lists in html inherit ids from the parent list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have an html code where i have used unordered lists to show directory structure.
On clicking li tag,i call a js function(say changecss()) where i block the display of child lis to make them visible.but on clicking the child lis.
if i click on the child li,they also call the same function changecss() .
They dont have onclick event attached with them but still they call the function while i click on those li.

Here is the code  :

  class 1
          
              subject1
- extra class 2
- extra class 3

```
        </li>
        <li>Subject 2</li>
        <li>Subject 3</li>
    </ul>

</li>
<li id="second"  onclick="showSubList(this)">Class 2
<ul style="display:none" >
        <li >subject1
            <ul >
                <li> extra class 2</li>
            <li>extra class 3</li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li>Subject 2</li>
        <li>Subject 3</li>
    </ul>


</li>
<li>Class 3</li>
<li>Class 4</li>
```

javaScript for this is :
function showSubList(e) {
        alert(e.id);

```
      if(e.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display == "none")
      {
         e.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="block";
          }
      else if(e.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display == "block")
      {
          e.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="none";
          }
   };
```

You can check here also:
http://jsfiddle.net/TTYMm/

Any idea about such behaviour?

Thanks.

here is the possible fix:
http://jsfiddle.net/TTYMm/1/

thanks Guys

Comment: welcome to SO.
please edi your post to put a valid jsfiddle link.
also, you might want to edit your message to corect a little the spell check(I is alwais writtent in capital).

Comment: @Kingalione please check the fiddle now .

Comment: I couldn't load your fiddle, so not sure if this is what you mean, but you can explicitly tell javascript to listen to a direct child link by using ">":

$("#my-list li").on("click"...

Will affect any li at any level contained in #my-list

BUT


$("#my-list > li").on("click"...

Will affect only li's contained in first level of #my-list

Answer (score 1):

No, `id`s are not inherited.

List items are contained by lists though. If the event isn't captured and prevented from propagating by the list item, it will [bubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_5%3a_Event_Propagation) through to the list, then to the list's parent, and so on.

Comment: How to prevent it from propagating?

Comment: Call [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation). You'll probably find it easier if you switch to using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event) first.

Comment: in my case children li  dont have any event attached.stopPropagation,bubbling etc come into picture if two elements are attached to the same event i guess.  From the fiddle,can you please tell me how the event is propagating in my case.

Comment: Then attach an event handler to them. Or test the `target` of the event in the high level handlers.

Comment: did you see the fiddle ? the child li returns the same id as of the parent.this behavior is fine?

Comment: That's because the event handler is attached to the parent. That's expected. Use `event.target` to figure out which element was actually clicked.

Comment: Without using eventListeners,is there any solution to this problem.i am not so good in Javascript.i can write basic code ..

Comment: Probably, but since intrinsic event handlers (`onclick` attributes and friends) inevitably make it harder to write and maintain, I've no desire to figure out how. `addEventListener` is the easy way.

Comment: i fixed it using  event.target property. thanks for the showing the way .

Answer (score 0):

Its normal behavior in case of event propagation.

Please read something more about it there http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow